# AS3 IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR event not catching if file doesn't exist

Tags: actionscript-3

This doesn't make any sense. I'm trying to load a simple text file. If the file name is just "jeffaberle.txt" then it works fine because that file exists in the location specified. However if the name is changed to "jeffaberle2.txt" the code produces an error because this file does not exist on the server.

I want the IOErrorEvent to fire if the file is missing, but it doesn't fire. There's clearly something I'm missing. Any suggestions?

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;

var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.postureviewer.com/trials/jeffaberle2.txt" + "?" + Math.random());  // + Math.random()
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
    if (urlLoader.data.trialversion == "true") {
        trace("true");
    } else {
        trace("false");
    }
}
function ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("ioErrorHandlerJeff: " + e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conflict since "http://www.postureviewer.com/trials/jeffaberle2.txt" returns 'data', but it is not in the form of name/value pairs that you are requesting via URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES.

In order to trigger the "IOErrorEvent" remove the URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES line so http errors (404 in this case) are thrown to your *ioErrorHandler*. Then in the *completeHandler* you can try to convert the data that you did received into name/value pairs. Doing this in a try/catch will allow you to catch bad data returns from your php script:

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;

var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.postureviewer.com/trials/jeffaberle2.txt" + "?" + Math.random());  // + Math.random()
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);

urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
    try {
        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);
        if (variables.trialversion == "true") {
            trace("true");
        } else {
            trace("false");
        }
    } catch (e:Error) {
        if (e.errorID == 2101) {
        // Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
           trace("Bad data returned from php : " + e.message);
        } else {
           trace(e.message);
        }
    }
}
function ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("ioErrorHandlerJeff: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: That solved the problem, but I'm not sure how to get the catch to activate. Tried changing the variable "trialversion" to "trialversion1" to see if that would throw the error, but it just defaulted to the else statement in the try part of the code. How could I test the catch part?

Comment: If the data returned from url request can not be decoded as a standard URL-encoded query string, the decode function called in the URLVariables() constructor would throw an error (2101). Just place a string in your file that would fail that type of decoding, i.e. "trail@true" is not a valid query string,  : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding

Comment: The reason I included the try/catch is I saw that the header response from your URL includes "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" "X-Pingback: http://postureviewer.com/xmlrpc.php" and thus if php failed and 'spewed' an error response to the URL request vs. the actual the file, you would pick that up since the php "Error response" would not be a decodable query string.

Comment: Wow, you know your actionscript. Thank you so much.

Comment: For those of you that didn't see the original text file: This text works fine: trialversion=true&startDate=September 24, 2015      But this text causes the catch code to run:  trialversion=true&startDate=September 24, 2015&trail@true

Answer (score 0):

You're not loading a "file", you're accessing a data resource with a URL.  The most likely solution is to process HTTPStatus events

```
...
urlLoader.addEventListener( HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler );

urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

function httpStatusHandler( e:HTTPStatusEvent ) : void
{
    switch ( e.status )
    {
        case 404:
            trace( "Resource missing!" );
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

You would rely on the IOErrorEvent if the streams were corrupted or the connection faulted.